# I'm trying to make a discord music bot but when I type a command it doesn't recognize it

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

After running this code I get this error = `Ignoring exception in command None: discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "join" is not found`

I get this error even though the code has ran for few weeks without any errors and without me changing anything.

I have no idea how to solve it, I have tried replaceing commands in commands.command() to bot.command(), but it didn't work.

It feels like I tried everything and I have no hope left.

Would appreciate any advice.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import youtube_dl

class music(commands.Cog):
  def __init__(self, client):
    self.client = client


@command.command()
async def join(self, ctx):
    await ctx.send("X")
    if ctx.author.voice is None: 
        await ctx.send("X")
    voice_channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
    if ctx.voice_client is None: 
        await voice_channel.connect()
    else:
        await ctx.voice_client.move_to(voice_channel)

@command.command()
async def dc(self,ctx):
    await ctx.voice_client.disconnect()
    await ctx.send("X")

@command.command()
async def p(self,ctx,url):
    ctx.voice_client.stop()
    FFMPEG_OPTIONS = {'before_options': '-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1   -reconnect_delay_max 5', 'options': '-vn'}
    YDL_OPTIONS ={'format':"bestaudio"}
    vc = ctx.voice_client

    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:
        info = ydl.extract_info(url, download=False)
        url2 = info['formats'][0]['url']
        source = await discord.FFmpegOpusAudio.from_probe(url2,**FFMPEG_OPTIONS)
        vc.play(source)

@command.command()
async def pause(self,ctx):
    await ctx.send("x") 
    await ctx.voice_client.pause()

@command.command()
async def resume(self,ctx):
    await ctx.send("x")
    await ctx.voice_client.resume() 



def setup(client):
  client.add_cog(music(client))
```

this is code for my main file

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext import  tasks
from discord.voice_client import VoiceClient
from random import choice
import music
import comments
from replit import db
from keepalive import keepalive


cogs=[music]
intents = discord.Intents.all()
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='?', intents = intents, case_insensitive=True)


for i in range(len(cogs)):
   cogs[i].setup(client)



@client.command(name='ping', help='.')
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send(f'Ping-pong: {round(client.latency * 1000)}ms')

status = ['X']

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    change_status.start()
    print('X')


@tasks.loop(seconds=20)
async def change_status():
    await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(choice(status)))



token = ""
with open("toke.txt") as file:
  token = file.read()

keepalive()
client.run(token)
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to indent every command in a class by 1 level of indentation and second, it's `@commands.command()` not `@command.command()`.

Here's the docs for cogs:
https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/master/ext/commands/cogs.html?highlight=cogs

EDIT: As I've written in my comment, heres an example on how to load cogs:

main file:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands


intents = discord.Intents.all()
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='?', intents = intents, case_insensitive=True)


cogs = ["music"]

for i in cogs:
    client.load_extension(f"cogs.{i}")


with open("token.txt") as file:
    token = file.read()

client.run(token)
```

This assumes the music.py file is stored in a folder named `cogs`, if that is not the case, edit the line `client.load_extension(f"cogs.{i}")` and replace the `cogs` with whatever your folder name is (or remove it if the file is stored in the same folder as your main.py).

And then in the music file:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

class music(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client


    @commands.command()
    async def play(self, ctx):
        print("test")


def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(music(client))
```

Comment: Hey, mb this was wrongly edited back from bot.command() I tried using @commands.command and indenting every command in class by 2 indentations as was shown in the documentation, but still the same error, any idea why it might be doing it ?

Comment: I have experimented a bit with that, and I think you are not loading the cog properly. I have edited my comment with a working example. I hope it works for you too.